# sum up the currency with an equal 1 ID carrying other data

Tags: php, arrays, sum

How do I sum up the currency(net due) with an equal 1 ID(employment_userid) carrying other data on the array below.

How do I sum up the currency(net due) with an equal 1 ID(employment_userid) carrying other data on the array below.

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [employment_userid] => 375
        [full_name] => Sean Sean
        [eng_name] => Sean Sean
        [account_num] => BDO - 12321321
        [net_due] => 6142.42
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [employment_userid] => 375
        [full_name] => Sean Sean
        [eng_name] => Sean Sean
        [account_num] => BDO - 12321321
        [net_due] => 6268.22
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [employment_userid] => 385
        [full_name] => Nathaniel Rada
        [eng_name] => Nathaniellll
        [account_num] => BDO - 12321321
        [net_due] => 13338.74
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [employment_userid] => 385
        [full_name] => Nathaniel Rada
        [eng_name] => Nathaniellll
        [account_num] => BDO - 12321321
        [net_due] => 13545.39
    )
```

result should be like this.

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [employment_userid] => 375
        [full_name] => Sean Sean
        [eng_name] => Sean Sean
        [account_num] => BDO - 12321321
        [net_due] => 12410.64
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [employment_userid] => 385
        [full_name] => Nathaniel Rada
        [eng_name] => Nathaniellll
        [account_num] => BDO - 12321321
        [net_due] => 26884.13
    )
```

thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$newArr = [];
foreach($bigArray as $key => $val)
{
    if(isset($newArr[$val['employment_userid']]))
    {
       $newArr[$val['employment_userid']]['net_due'] += $val['net_due'];
    } else 
    {
       $newArr[$val['employment_userid']]['employment_userid'] = $val['employment_userid'];
       $newArr[$val['employment_userid']]['full_name']         = $val['full_name'];
       $newArr[$val['employment_userid']]['eng_name']          = $val['eng_name'];
       $newArr[$val['employment_userid']]['account_num']       = $val['account_num'];
       $newArr[$val['employment_userid']]['net_due']           = $val['net_due'];
    }
}

$arr = array_values($newArr); //index keys of arrays from 0
```